# complex multiply instruction Hexagon DSP

Tags: signal-processing, multiplayer, hexagon-dsp

I'm preparing my presenation about Hexagon DSP for collage project, I can't understand the flow of this complex multiply instruction.
how multiply done !!? 
[image: Heagon DSP]

Comment: Are you asking how it's implemented in hardware?  Or how you would use it?